# Time series change point detection

Tags: python, time-series, trend

What is the best statistic way in python to detect the points in red on my time-series (see attached image)

I have time series data and some historical change points and I want to detect a change point ASAP in the time series.

[image]

I have calculated the gradient (orange curve in the picture below) and tried to detect peak above a certain threshold, but still have some wrong points (like the one surrounded in red):

[image]

Comment: you could train a classifier that looks at surroundings (e.g. 25 steps left and right?). This could be 1D convolutional neural net. You would ofc need to provide training data.

Comment: alternatively you could take absolute of np.gradient (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) and take max values of this signal.

Comment: hello @ikamen
thank you for your response, do you have any examples ? since I am new at all of this.

Comment: @ikamen, I am interested on 1d convolutional NN to detect this feature on the time series. Do you have any example ?

Comment: Did you figure out the solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic problem of finding the point of change. There are a large number of algorithms. I recommend that you pay attention to the following library https://github.com/deepcharles/ruptures

Comment: Hello, I have tried rupture library and other method but I always had wrong positive change points.

Comment: Describe in more detail what exactly do you need to discover?  A sharp change in the trend? Only a positive trend change?

Comment: I edited my post with more details, the idea is to detect the points in red in the time series. I try to figure out te behaviour of the curve at these points.

Comment: Why is the point circled in red not correct?

Comment: the curve is measures of pressure in oil pipeline, vertical axis are particular points validated with experts that represent when a robot pass through the pipeline.
So the idea is to detect the future points like this using pressure data.
For now, the red point is wrong because experts didn't detect a robot passage at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how useful it is for this particular time series, but if somebody cares a Bayesian method, one possibility is the Rbeast package developed by my team (https://pypi.org/project/Rbeast/, and install via `pip install Rbeast`). Unlike classical methods, Bayesian techniques often provide a richer set of diagnostic statistics to help interpret the results. Rbeast, for example, can tell not just whether there is a changepoint or not but also the changepoint occurrence probability over time. (It is not better than other methods, but just offering alternative insights.) Here is a toy example：

```
import Rbeast as rb
nile, year = rb.load_example('nile')                     # nile is a 1d Python array or numpy vector
o          = rb.beast( nile, start=1871, season='none')  # season='none' bcz the data has no seasonal/periodic component
rb.plot(o, title='Annual streamflow of the Nile River')
```

[image]